# How to use db-mysql extension for NodeJS under Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, node.js

I'm using NodeJS under Windows (with node.exe downloaded from NodeJS site). I would like to use this db-mysql extension with it ( https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/ )

I have no idea how to use it. Is it necessary to rebuild the whole node.exe or is it possible to build just the extension? I'm not able to run NPM with node.exe (it results in error) as the installation instructions says.

Thanks

Comment: My advice is, Ubuntu 10 is a great OS, super easy to use. I stated on Rails and would not turn back to Windows web-dev

Comment: Finally I'm using Cygwin and I'm quite satisfied with it.

Comment: My advice is, Windows 7 is a great OS, super easy to use. I started on PHP and would not turn back to Ubuntu web-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but you will have to have a full tool-chain(Cygwin) that can compile c. That means you have three alternatives:

1. Use linux (in a VM) or mac
2. Install node from cygwin ( https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows) )
3. Use another database (eg. node-dirty: https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty) that doesn't need to be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use NPM (Node Package Manager) with the Windows executable node.exe as for all I know.

Instead you should download the zip/tar module from https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/downloads and place the contents into a *node_modules* folder above your script(s).

**Example structure:**

```
/nodestuff
  /node_modules
    /db-mysql // The module
  /script
    app.js // Your script
```

Then just follow the instructions on https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/ in order to create a database connection.
Good luck.