# how to communicate between nodejs and DB

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

I want to know how to communicate between nodejs and database.
I found the similar question and tried with 'db-mysql module; 
but it doesn't work at window.
it has a problem with install and I found that the problem will never get fixed.
the problem is node-waf, and i found it'll never support at window. 
Then how can I communicate with Database, with js file?
If JS file Using Node.js, isn't it only works in the directory that nodejs is installed? And Isn't it only be a JS file? 
How can i using the database and db query... such as mysql query.... and how to connect?? Plz help ME..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not developing with node.js in Windows so I haven't tested myself any of the answers provided below.

There seem to be more than one module to query mysql from node.js, check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889152/1366519

Also, https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/ seems to work in cygwin per this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7025137/1366519